# AngularJS Typescript Service Inject Error

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to migrate AngularJS to typesript. I faced a weird issue of testController being undefined incase I define injections with static $inject like below.

Controller TS

```
class TestController {
    private customerName : string;
    private customerLink : string;
    private contactDetails : any;
    private userPosts : any;

    static $inject = ["TestService", "CustomerContactService"];
    constructor(private TestService: ITestService, private CustomerContactService: any) {
        console.log("inside constructor TestController");
    }

    init(customerName, customerLink) {
        if(customerName && customerLink) {
            this.customerName = TestConstant.HELLO + customerName;
            this.customerLink = customerLink;
        }
    }

    getPosts() {
        this.testService.getUserPosts().then((response : ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) =>{
            this.userPosts = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        });
    }

    getContactDetails() {
        this.customerContactService.getContacts("sales").then((response : ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) =>{
            this.contactDetails = JSON.stringify(response);
        });
    }
}

angular
    .module("testModule")
    .controller("testController", TestController);
```

Service TS

```
interface ITestService {
    getUserPosts() : ng.IPromise<ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>>;
}

class TestService implements ITestService {

    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor(private $http : ng.IHttpService) {

    }

    getUserPosts() : ng.IPromise<ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>> {
        return this.$http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    }
}

angular
    .module("testModule")
    .service("testService", TestService);
```

**However**, if I use in the following in my **controller**

```
static AngularDependencies = ["TestService", "CustomerContactService"];
OR
static helloWorld = ["TestService", "CustomerContactService"];
```

everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? and how do I use static $inject as that seems to be a convention?

Error:[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=testController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

TIA

Comment: Why do you need 'static $inject = ["TestService", "CustomerContactService"];' ? Will the normal constructor injection not suffice?

Comment: its added for minification purpose, and also without that line, it throws injection error in the console.

Comment: I'm surprised you're able to get it to work. Each time you call `angular.module("testModule", [])` you are creating a new app named "testModule". You should only be doing that once and subsequent references to the app should be `angular.module("testModule")` without the second parameter.

Comment: Correct, we have a separate module builder which injects all the available module with empty dependencies. Have updated the code. But the issue still persists!